# how to improve speed of multiple filter on ng-repeat with a large data list in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a list of large data (more than 200 rows). And every row have a more 7,8 columns, All are coming from the REST API (it took 5,6 seconds).

In Angularjs Controller :

```
 $http.get(path).then(function (resp) {
    $scope.listOfData= resp.data;
});
```

In Html page :

```
<table>
                <tr class="header">
                    <th>id</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>status</th>
                    <th>mobile</th>
                    <th>Gender</th>
                    <th>location</th>
                 </tr>

                 <tr ng-repeat="data in listOfData |orderBy: id | filter:folder | filter:status.value | filter:xyz | filter:abc">
                    <th>{{data.id}}</th>
                    <th>{{data.name}}</th>
                    <th>{{data.status}}</th>
                    <th>{{data.mobile}}</th>
                    <th>{{data.gender}}</th>
                    <th>{{data.location}}</th>
                 </tr>
     </table>
```

With ng-repeat I am using multiple filters (All filters are from select tag).

All these code are working fine. But when I am Iterating the list of data via ng-repeat, it took 15-20 seconds to load complete data.

My first question is , How to reduce the loading time for ng-repeat ?

and second question is, When I am filtering the data is working fine but It's took some time for filtering (some time, screen hang up for 3,4 seconds).

So can you please tell me where m doing wrong, and how to fixed it, so my page will load faster and multiple filter will be perform more easily and faster ?

Thank you so much

Comment: Create one function on $scope.isVisible() which will evaluate all filters together and return  boolean value. and use ng-show="isVisible()" . This will save dom deletion and creation.

Comment: Also, if your collection is not changing, you only need one time binding. This will improve the performance. 
You can do one time binding as {{::name}} in latest version of angularjs. Or use https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce for older angularjs versions.

Comment: Create a demo that replicates this. There must be something else in there other than just filters causing this sort of lag

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of things you can do to improve performance:

1. Limit the number of items shown. Limit it to a small-ish number of items to show (50). If you need to show more items, add a Show More button at the bottom, that bumps up the limit.

   `<table>
       ...
       <tr ng-repeat="data in listOfData |orderBy: id | filter:folder | filter:status.value | filter:xyz | filter:abc | limitTo: maxLimit">
       ...
       </tr>
   </table>
   <a ng-click="maxLimit = maxLimit + 50">Show More...</a>`
2. One way binding - as Ganesh pointed out, if your data isn't change, then use one way binding instead: `<th>{{::data.id}}</th>`